# postfix cannot send email

Tags: email, postfix, port-forwarding

I'd like to mention that im really new to this so please bear with me. I'm trying to setup a forum software to send emails via postfix but I think my server has the port 25 blocked. I tried running these:

works:

```
ping alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
```

don't work:

```
telnet alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
telnet 66.249.93.114 25
```

tried flushing iptables and then using these rules but didn't work either:

```
sudo iptables --flush

sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X
```

doing a telnet on 25 port to localhost url works but nothing when telnet'ing in none local urls.

mail.log:

```
Oct 17 01:20:24 webhost postfix/smtp[3642]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c03::1a]:25: Connection timed out

Oct 17 01:20:24 webhost postfix/smtp[3643]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c03::1a]:25: Connection timed out

Oct 17 01:20:24 webhost postfix/smtp[3642]: 4744380032: to=<targetMail@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=2892, delays=2741/0.03/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f$
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be your ISP or hosting provider filtering outbound connections to port 25 to prevent botnet spam. Use

```
traceroute -n alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
```

and/or

```
tcptraceroute -n alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
```

to check which hop is blocking the connection.

Comment: 1st: http://pastebin.com/i0dPnnmZ 
2nd: http://pastebin.com/hmPm8bCC

Comment: Both outputs appear to be from `traceroute`. Were you running the command on different hosts?

Comment: i think the software automatically used traceroute instead of tcptraceroute cause i didnt have tcptraceroute installed. The outcome is exactly the same though. I just installed and tested it again

Comment: I also tried 587 port but didn't reach the destination: http://pastebin.com/q0VEGuJj

Comment: If the output of `tcptraceroute` is the same as the output of the second trace in your first comment, then it does look to me like your provider is filtering outbound connections (at least to port 25). `nmap` shows port 587 on that host as "filtered". For submission you have to use a different host.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail recommends connecting to `smtp.gmail.com` on port `587` for TLS/STARTTLS or `465` for SSL. http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Comment: tried 587, didn't reach the destination:
http://pastebin.com/q0VEGuJj

Comment: You're looking at the wrong host. You're tracing the route to one of GMail's MXs when you *should* be tracing the route to one of their submission hosts. Compare the output of `host -t MX gmail.com` and `host -t A smtp.gmail.com`.